# Trilogy Addict badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, stack-exchange, badge-request

We should have a gold badge celebrating people who achieve 3000+ rep on all three of the trilogy sites (perhaps even include meta?).

This would be awarded on all sites at the same time.

I did a bit of poking around and noticed that [splattne](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6461?tab=accounts#sort-top) meets this criteria. [you should go outside once in a while ;-)]

Comment: I like it, but I'd make the number larger.

Comment: I would never get it because ServerFault is definitely not my realm

Comment: Can I sub Meta in for ServerFault?

Comment: @TheTxi, meta is too easy!

Comment: What happens when another site is added to the trilogy?

Comment: \*Head Explodes\*

Comment: @TheTXI: I'll hook up you in SF if you hook me up in SO...  Oh wait, that would be frowned upon, wouldn't it?

Comment: Badges are awarded per site. Would this be a new kind of network-wide badge, or would it be awarded on each of the three sites?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like this, it encourages people to participate on all sites... on the other hand, programmers are not sysadmins and it may be difficult for them to achieve that much reputation on serverfault (and vice versa, and there are more examples for the other combinations of audiences)

I know I couldn't get 3000 on serverfault for example

Perhaps a badge for getting that rep on 3 sites (whichever ones, counting meta)

Comment: I fall into the same camp. I should be able to get 3000+ on SuperUser - there are questions I can answer there - I just need to be a bit more active. I don't think I could hit 1000 on ServerFault even if I spent all day every day there.

Comment: me too, I could never hit 3,000 on SF, and I don't think I'll spend that much time on SU (so probably won't hit that one either), but I like the idea of recognizing people who are skilled in all three areas.

Comment: But you could, by contributing questions (when they happen to come up) and contributing answers when you happen to know them. Spend some off hours (when the heavy hitters are away) and use mad googling, and you'll get at least some point.

Comment: @devinb: that's one argument for why they might not want to create the badge.  It could encourage a lot of google-generated answers by non-experts.

Comment: I don't think that the one badge will cause that to happen more that it is already.

Comment: @Joel, if the answers are correct/upvoted does it matter how the person developed the answer? (plagiarism aside)

Comment: Juan: Well right, but people don't *have* to get badges :-)  It is almost the 'Jack Of All Trades' or 'Rounded' Badge or something.

Comment: @Kyle, talk for yourself... I **have** to get them =)

Comment: @Juan gotta catch em all

Comment: @ChrisF Well you eventually made it.

Answer (score 6):

I think two badges in this vein should be added--one silver, one gold:

**Trilogy Addict** - Silver: > 3000 rep on any combination of three sites

**Ubergeek** - Gold: > 5000 rep on SOFU (Meta doesn't count)

Comment: Total Addict - Gold: >10k rep on all sites.

Comment: Seriously? - Gold: >100k on all sites

Comment: @Troggy, that would be a platinum badge, especially seeing as Jon Skeet has the most rep and is currently at 88.8K on SO, and no one is near that on SF (top 15K) or SU (top 8K)

Comment: @Troggy +1 for the Gears of War Reference, although I'm scared what your Seriously 2.0 Badge would require... "Getting one of each Badge listed on the /badges Page on each site (incl Meta) and achieving 250.000 combined reputation"?

Comment: How about: **Polymath** - Gold: >1000 on five sites?

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned before, absolute values of rep are hard to set because they vary so much between sites - and because you'll eventually get there even with a very slow burn.

How about a badge (awarded only once) for being in the first page (or first n pages) of some number of sites? (The details about including/excluding meta etc are worth separate discussion; I'm only interested in the general idea for now.)

I don't know how easy this would be to implement without killing the server, but it would be an indicator of being a "high flyer" on multiple sites.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great idea.  Should definitely have a silver and a gold.  There are definitely different atmospheres on each of the different sites and this would encourage people to expand their horizons (or at least the badge lovers :P ).

I think it greatly benefits everyone to spend a little time "on the other side".  Even though I have less than a [**milliSkeet**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13827/can-we-measure-reputation-in-milliskeets) of rep on SO I've not been discouraged from watching things there and learning first hand from some the best in the industry.  I started out life as a sysadmin and am relatively new to the coding side of things.  I have noticed that my code quality and practices have gone up *significantly* in the couple of months that I've been watching SO.

The better one gets in all 3 areas that the trilogy cover, the more you'll understand how to cover those aspects and the more complete your solutions can be.  Anything (within reason) that can be done to encourage that is worth considering, IMHO.